# Regex query syntax examples in kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to find the different kinds of syntax I can give in regex type of query through kibana, but I was not able to find any information on this.
I am running logstash and elasticsearch in the backend.
Any answer or example will be helpful.

Comment: That edit doesn't come close to justifying reopening this question. It's way too broad and too vague. Please identify a specific problem or question about coding. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on [ask] good questions and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

so any regular expressions are valid in grok as well. The regular expression library is Oniguruma.

I took this from the logstash docs online.

Also from [a Google Groups post]:
Kibana is a web interface which stay in front of ElasticSearch: to understand
the query syntax you have to know something more about Apache Lucene,
which is the text search engine used by ElasticSearch.

Here's a small tutorial about the query styles you can use with Lucene and
by inheritance with your Kibana web interface:

<s>http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html</s> This link is dead, I'm not sure but [this might be an adequate replacement.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180209081154/https://daysincode.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/lucene-query.html) (I've saved it into wayback machine as it keeps dying...)

See also the official [Lucene Query Syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description).

Comment: Thanks @MusicalShore

Comment: The cached link isn't working now either

Comment: @darkwing the original link that was cached was still up so i've added it to wayback machine and added that link in instead.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @GPPK!